# Accessing widgets from Window*

Tags: c++, widget, gtkmm

In my code, I have a Gtkmm `Gtk::Window*` and I wanna access it's widgets frequently. How can I do it?

What I mean is to see if there's any feature like `Builder->get_widget()`. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. There are some methods for finding children of a widget, but it's a colossal pain.
Personally, I always subclass Gtk::Window and make public (or make public functions) if I need to mess with any widgets outside the class.

Gtk::Bin class where get_child() is: http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Bin.html#a8e7fef9251afa541318bb53dcf3098db

Comment: Yes, I twiddled with it since yesterday and I finally realized that the method you're saying is the easiest and most logical and perhaps the best. Thank you ;-)